# Conditional formatting of all apex:inputFields in a VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, css

I have several apex:inputFields in my VF Page. I want to change their style depending on whether they are filled or empty. I know I can achieve this for a sepcific Inputfield by:

```
<apex:inputField type="auto" html-placeholder="Betrag" value="{!Bilanz__c.Interne_K_ufer_Kosten1__c}" style="{!IF(ISBLANK(Bilanz__c.Interne_K_ufer_Kosten1__c), 'background-color:lightgrey;', 'border:0;')}"/>
```

Which turns the background of the field to lightgrey, when empty. And makes the borders disappear, when filled. Works like a charm.

The problem is that I really want to avoid doing this to all my Fields (50+). style="..." currently checks for ISBLANK(Name-of-actual-Salesforce-Field). If I would want to handle the style via CSS, I would need a way to check for the emptiness of that inputfield without its specific name. Something like:

```
<style>
.inputField {
    {!IF(ISBLANK(value), 'background-color:lightgrey;', 
    'border:0;')}
}
</style>
```

However, that does not work. Is there a way to generally check if an apex:Inputfield is empty in the css part of my VF Page?

I hope I clarified my problem sufficiently. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you tried to use Visualforce component and pass attribute there?

Comment: You could use jQuery on the page to iterate through the DOM elements and checking their values, then set the style